# Iteration in Libreoffice Calc using Formulas

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Basically i want to turn this: 
=A2*B2+A3*B3+A4*B4

into something like this:
=for i in 2 to 4; do summ=summ+SUM(Ai*Bi); done

Is it possible with Calc's Formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear if you specifically require an iterative formula for some reason, but that general form of calculation is what SUMPRODUCT does.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A4,B2:B4)
```

This multiplies the associated values in each range and then adds up the products as you describe.  It's equivalent to your formula:

```
=A2*B2+A3*B3+A4*B4
```

There are a lot of online tutorials on using SUMPRODUCT, starting with the [Microsoft Office documentation](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e).

It is a very powerful function because it lets you do a lot of array-type calculations without needing an array formula.  The ranges don't need to be simple range definitions, they can be formulas that do calculations on the cells in the range.  So you can do things like test each cell in a range to see if that cell meets certain criteria, and use SUMPRODUCT to do calculations selectively on qualifying cells.  Check out tutorials like [this one from Exceljet](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) for an idea of more advanced ways you can use it.